# Can I print to a printer on a client server using PrintDocument?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I have the following code in my ASP.NET C# (Windows Form) which I can print to a printer on my local PC. But what I want to do is be able to print to a printer on a server. Is there anyway to specify the server address along with the printer name?

I hardcoded the printer name just for testing purposes. This printerName is a printer on the server. If I replace it with a printer on my local PC it prints. I just don't know how to specify the correct path for the printer on the server.

```
    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        printerName = "AMI-Zebra";                      // on ABB system

        printerServer = "172.18.10.22";
        trans = "132980877";
        qty = txtQty.Text;


        Printing(PrinterName);

    }


    private void Printing(string pname)
{
    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = pname;

        PageSettings ps = new PageSettings();
        PaperSize pz = new PaperSize();

        pz.Height = 650;
        pz.Width = 400;
        ps.PaperSize = pz;

        printDoc.DefaultPageSettings = ps;
        printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc_PrintPage);  
    printDoc.Print();
}

    private void printDoc_PrintPage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {           
        string cnstr = ConnString; 

        string wc = string.Empty;
        string item = string.Empty;

        string currDt = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();     // sam new 11/20/2012


        //Pen p1   = Pens.Black;
        Pen p2 = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        Pen p3 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        Brush b1 = System.Drawing.Brushes.Black;

        Font f1 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
        Font f2 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12);
        Font f3 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
        Font f4 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
        Font f5 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Bold);   

        Font fb = new Font("Free 3 of 9", 40);


        System.Drawing.StringFormat drawFormat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical);

        e.Graphics.DrawString("WIP LABEL", f5, b1, 370, 100, drawFormat);  
        e.Graphics.DrawString("MFG Date", f2, b1, 380, 500, drawFormat);              
        e.Graphics.DrawString(currDt, f3, b1, 350, 500, drawFormat);
    }
```

Comment: ASP.NET C# (Windows Form) ? Do you mean you use this code in winform and try to use it in asp.net ?

Comment: @NicoD No im using a windows form vs. webform

Comment: And the printer is shared ? if not, shared the printer over the network. Install it on pc executing the winform app and it should be fine. But maybe i don't get it...